# `git checkout commit_id` still works after `git gc`

Tags: git, github, version-control, branch

I have a commit that should have been left dangling/unreachable after a rebase on branch it was attached to was executed, and the commit was squashed in the process. `git rebase -i <other commit id>`

Now, if i do `git branch --contains ID` i get nothing.

So then i do a `git gc --prune=now --aggressive`. Now i *assume* that this should effectively delete the dangling commit , so no more references to it should work, but `git checkout ID` still works.

Any idea on what i'm doing wrong here? I also did a `git remote remove origin` since i was afraid the checkout was actually working with the origin, but the results are the same.
Thanks in advance

Comment: It's still reachable from the reflog.

Comment: `git reflog expire --expire=now --expire-unreachable=now --all` and the checkout still works

Comment: It's downright *hard* to remove things from Git. The full process is: (1) update branch and tag names to make sure none of them refers to the commit; (2) check for non-branch, non-tag names (such as stashes); (3) expire reflogs; (4) run `git gc --prune=now` or `git repack -ad; git prune`. See the last few pages of https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-filter-branch.html.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following command to generate a symbolic reference — if possible — for your commit.

`git name-rev <hash>`

Stumbled upon a similar situation, when a `tag` was still referencing a dangling commit. This command returned the tag and the relative location of my commit `~1`.

If this command does not return a helpful result, it may also be referenced from the reflog. Before running the garbage collection, have you tried expiring the unreachable commits?

`git reflog expire --expire-unreachable=now --all`

**Edit:**
Im a bit baffled by the fact, even the last command was not able to force garbage collection to pick up your commit. What size is your repository? Since you used the `--aggressive` flag on your first garbage collect, could it be, that the first gc-process was still in progress, when you attempted the second one? You can use `git gc --force` in combination with your other arguments to instantly run gc, even when there is another garbage collection running.

> **--force**
>
> Force git gc to run even if there may be another git gc instance running on this repository.

Comment: this returns `a756b32655824089472e936b6e6eae6d0cc12fd4 undefined`, which I assume really means undefined, and not some weirdly named tag

Comment: I updated my answer, but just now saw your comment in which you clarified, you already attempted this.

Comment: Which size does your repo have? May it be the case that your initial `--aggressive` gc was still running, when you attempted the second one after expiring the unreachables?

Comment: Was the commit still checked out while you ran the gc?

Comment: the GC was a blocking process, and i did not run anything while it was executing. The repo size is pretty tiny. Except a recently added 200M binary which goes untouched, it's more or less under 1Mb

Comment: Interesting. Let me know when you found a solution :)